# Can you dynamically decide what operator to use?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to do something like this, where based on some condition I decide whether to set a val to another or to increment it.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but how would I make this work?

```
process_wager(@wagers[@street.current][@action.abbrev])
process_wager(@wagers[@street.current][:total])
process_wager(@actions[@action.abbrev])
process_wager(@wagered)

def process_wager val
    @condition ? val = @amt : val += @amt
end
```

I know I could do

```
@wagers[@street.current][@action.abbrev] = process_wager(@wagers[@street.current][@action.abbrev])
```

but I am hoping for a tidier way like up above.

Comment: `val` is a local variable in your `process_wager` method and its assigment will do nothing. It won't change the object you have passed to the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not:

```
val = @condition ? @amt : val + @amt
```

Comment: I don't udnerstand that line of code.  Did you mean val == @condition?  @condition is just a boolean so that wouldn't make sense, and I don't see what val = boolean does.

Comment: No, this assigns to `val` either `@amt` or `val + @amt` depending on the truth value of `@condition`. Assignment has lower precedence, so it happens last.

Comment: Pretty much the whole point of the `? :` operator is to be able to do that.  :-)